# How to overcome from the error

Tags: c#

i m making add,edit delete module...For that i have the following code in the c#,

```
private void listOfCompany_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(updID.ToString());
        con.ConnectionString = @"PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\mayur patil\\My Documents\\Dairy_db\\tblCompany_1.mdb";
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string sql = "SELECT * From tblCompany_1 WHERE ID="+updID;

        da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(ds);
       // dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        textBox1.Text = dr.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
        textBox4.Text = dr.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
       /* int t = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dr.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dr.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dr.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        }*/


    }
```

when i debug the application, then on add,edit and delete button, it gives me error at the "DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];" that "IndexOutOf RangeException was handled" and the error is "There is no row at position 0."...How should i overcome from this?

Comment: I would check that that ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count is not 0 before attempting to create the DataRow

Comment: Put a breakpoint at line "DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];" and see if your "ds" variable has anything inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that suggests there's no record with that ID. You should check for that before going ahead and trying to use it. You can use `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count` to find out how many rows were returned.

You should *also* start using parameterized queries instead of including values directly within the SQL statement you're building, in order to avoid SQL injection attacks. If the ID is an integer then it probably isn't a problem here, but generally parameterized SQL queries are the way forward.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not working.It is giving the error that "    Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Data.DataRow' "

Comment: @Barbie: It can't be the same error, given that you were talking about an exception before, and now you're talking about a compile-time error. Presumably you've changed the code - update your question so we know *how* you've changed the code.

Comment: @Barbie: Did you consider what the `Count` property returns? It returns *how many datarows are in the table*. It isn't a DataRow, it's an int. The point is that you need to know how many results have been returned - if it's returned 0 results, you shouldn't ask for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
DataRow dr;

for(int i = 0; i<ds.Tables.Count; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j<ds.Tables[i].Rows.Count; j++){
    dr = ds.Tables[i].Rows[j];
    //Do something with dr.
  }
}
```

Note: It is possibly "Length" in stead of "Count". Can't remember right now:p

Comment: what i have to do with dr? Can you please tell me?

Comment: [DataRow Expample](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datarow)

Essetially, this is what you need to know. The use of the datarow defines what your program does. I can't tell you what your program should do.